# SQL select statement. Modifying all numbers in a column.

Tags: sql, ms-access

How do I replace all numbers in a column of a table to multiply by 0.6. 
Let's say the column reads:

```
1
2
3
```

I want it to become:

```
0.6
1.2
1.8
```

Comment: you mean multiply, right ?

Comment: Still unclear whether you want the numbers multiplied directly in the table, or upon selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE mytable
   SET mycolumn = mycolumn * 0.6;
```

Comment: Assuming the column is of type DECIMAL.

Comment: Doesn't the precision of the Decimal column also come into play?

Answer (score 3):

Go to the SQL view and type:

```
select columnname*0.6 from tablename
```

Replace columnname and table with your table/column names. By the way, that's multiplying by 0.6, not dividing.

Comment: If this works, you SO saved me 18 friking hours of work! HAHA

Comment: @user425815 .. I pray it to god you were not working on that for 18 hours.